# Is there any website having command line environment of Linux, for practicing commands?

Tags: linux, shell

I was wondering whether I could practice Linux commands and shell scripting, online, over a website which could provide me an editor to practice them. And I know that probably the easiest thing to do would be to download a Linux LIVE CD and then practice shell scripting, but apart from it, I want to practice them online, anywhere I want, anytime I want and on any system, without bothering about booting from a LIVE CD.

Comment: Look for web-based SSH clients and a free shell account with SSH access somewhere. You'll still be at the mercy of any firewall you might be behind, but you won't need to download or install any software, which might be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for this: http://bellard.org/jslinux/

It's an online linux terminal, all done in javascript.

It runs in your browser and has some functionality for you to paste/retrieve large ammounts of text (e.g. scripts you create).

Comment: I would strongly suggest against this. The JS Emulator was written purely as a challenge and may not be secure enough. Also, running the whole kernel in your browser memory means it's extremely slow and inefficient.

Comment: @darnir secure for what? OP wants to practice linux commands without the hassle of installing anything. It is not a security or performance constrained operation by any measure. And you can't argue with the convenience of a system on a webpage.

Answer (score 2):

A nice tool that you could put on a USB key : [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).
  This will give you, in windows, a bash shell, and many unix tools (close to the linux ones, but much slower as many things that are usually builtin in bash induce re-invocation of the shell in mobaXterm. And also the pipes are emulated, making reinvocation much more often than in a real unix/linux. But it's still useable, and quite nice.). And a lot of tools to connect to other servers (ssh, scp, etc).

Another way: a real linux within windows : Many exists, such as the minimal [PuppyLinux](http://www.puppylinux.org/) or the bigger/faster (and more complexly mixed with windows) [AndLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/) ... Put them also on a USB key/disk, and you'll have it with you almost anywhere.

Finally, to more closely match your request, you have online shells listed in [this thread](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/13803-shell-accounts.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a free instance on Amazon EC2 for a year.  Simply register and create a t1.micro instance, which is quite capable of running a decent little website.